# How to write GUI in the tweak program of iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, tweak, cydia-substrate

Wen can write the GUI of app with nib,storyboard,or code in the common legal project that can be summitted to the AppStore.But in the tweak of iOS open development, usually we write the .xm code to hook or do anything else to implement some features, maybe we need the GUI to interactive with the users, and the GUI part will communicate with the tweak part to achieve certain functions. how can we make the GUI part like we do in the legal project? How can we add the tweak part to an existed common legal project?
Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you please add some code or links and clean up your post a bit?  I'd like to help but I honestly can't tell what you are doing or what you want to do.

Comment: You need to code your GUI. Refer apple's UIKit documentation.